# Taking over fortressses before weakening changes quests?

Tags: far-cry-4

In Far Cry 4 I just took over De Pleur's fortress. It was still marked as hard (weirdly enough I found it way easier than the average 'easy' outpost).
I have heard I'm supposed to do some quests to weaken the defences of the fortress before attempting to take it over (unless you're feeling courageous).

**Does taking over the fortress before weakening it's defences unable me to do those quests?**
How do I recognize quests that weaken the fortresses defences?
Are there any benefits to taking over the fortress early?

I see a Longinus quest on the map nearby the fortress. Not sure if it has anything to do with it since I haven't done it yet.
I assume quests to weaken the fortress are either unskippable story missions or unnecesary side quests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without giving away too many spoilers, there shouldn't be any restrictions or punishments for taking down a fortress while the difficulty is "hard". Longinus quests have nothing to do with fortresses. **The story missions would eventually weaken the fortress but there's nothing stopping you from doing them early.**

The main benefit to taking over the fortresses is that outposts in the area won't be subjected to random take-over attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. So fortresses are basically just bigger and harder outposts right? So the weakening of fortresses is a side effect of story missions I will have to do anyway. I'm going to give other people also a chance to answer before accepting yours :)